# Accessing specific controller in grails shiro plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, shiro

I have a grails application in which I am using shiro plugin to add security. I do not give access to any of the urls without login to any user. All goes fine. Now I want to find whether there is any way to allow access to some of the urls without login ? Some links should be working without login.

Comment: I don't think anyway of doing this without some automated software which follows links. But when you have set security filter for all controller and all actions, you can be sure that no controller/action can be accessed without being logged in

Comment: I just want a few controllers/actions to be accessable without login; currently my all controllers/actions are not accessable without login

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's easy. If you've a standard shiro setup, you'll find a `ShiroSecurityFilters.groovy` in your projects `conf`-folder which looks something like this:

```
class SecurityFilters {
  def filters = {
    all(uri: "/**") {
      before = {
        // Ignore direct views (e.g. the default main index page).
        if (!controllerName) return true
        // Access control by convention. 
        accessControl() 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

just replace it with something like this:

```
class SecurityFilters {
  def filters = {
    all(uri: "/**") {
      before = {
        // Ignore direct views (e.g. the default main index page).
        if (!controllerName) return true
        // Access control by convention. 
        if ((controllerName+':'+actionName) in ['book:view', 'book:list']) {
          return true
        } else {
          accessControl() 
        }
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

This will make the two actions `list` and `view` of the `bookController` accessible to everyone.

Hope that helps...